# How to change image in a directory by uploading a new one to the webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and wanted to ask how to change picture on the website via some sort of an "admin" page.
Right now I have 2 sites: first is a main site that shows a picture which located in "images" folder. Second one will be my "admin" page. I want to give access to that page so that person who'll need to change the picture on the 1st site won't need to go to the "images" folder. So I want to have an upload button on the 2nd site which will change an already existing `image.jpeg` with a new one.
How can I make that stuff?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite that image.jpeg in the images folder or do you want to keep that image and upload a new picture?

Comment: I need to overwrite it actually

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], $file_location
```

You can simply use this function in php to upload an image with the same name i.e image.jpeg in the same directoy. It will overwrite the previous image and when you refresh the page the new image will load on your first site. If you encounter cache issue in the browser and it still shows old picture you can concatenate a random number at the end of the source of the image like this:

```
src=path_and_name_of_file.extension?randomNumber
```

Comment: I'll try it. Let you know If I encounter any issues.

Comment: okay I guess I can't do that cuz I don't even know how to work with php and where I should add the function u sent me. shouldn't even start all of that. Thank you anyway, Saad.